# How to route the first URI segment using NGINX as a reverse-proxy?

Tags: nginx, routes, uri, nginx-reverse-proxy, segment

I'm trying to construct an architecture/infrastructure on Amazon Web Services. Today I have an EC2 working like a gateway, with NGINX on the background. Btw, I'm new with NGINX.

The last week I had this NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # I put * for hide the real domain name
    server_name ******.com.ar www.******.com.ar;

    location / {
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
         proxy_pass         "http://private.ip.1:80/";
    }
}
```

And it worked great! When I go to www.domain.com.ar, I get a redirect to private ip 1 on port 80.

But, nowdays, I need to adjust the config file a bit.

1) First, I need to redirect some known paths to private ip 1 (ex. /company, /portfolio, /services, /contact and subsequences: /company/ourvision, /services/software, /contact/workwithus). I'm using NodeJS, not PHP.

2) And if none of the before paths get a match, I need to get the first URI segment as a wildcard (ex. http://domain.com.ar/*) matching only this characters: **A-z0-9** and send to private ip 2 on port 3000, also I need sending the wildcard word too (ex. http://private.ip.2:3000/wildcard-word)

I was only trying to success on my second point, but I couldn't deal with it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ******.com.ar www.******.com.ar;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://private.ip.1:80/";
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*)/?$ { 
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://private.ip.2:3000/$1";
    }
}
```

But this isn't working.
When I go to http://example.com.ar I go directly to the private ip 2 on port 3000. Btw, in another scenario, I get the follow error when I use the **nginx -t** command: *"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location*

So, can anyone help this noob to solve his problem? Thanks in advance. I will let the links that I was reading below:

- [nginx rule for wildcard url](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-rule-for-wildcard-url)
- [nginx location based on uri path](https://serverfault.com/questions/737168/nginx-location-based-on-uri-path/737175)
- [How to do URL Redirects with Nginx](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-redirect-urls-with-nginx/)
- [How to rewrite URI nginx reverse proxy using proxy_pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394957/how-to-rewrite-uri-nginx-reverse-proxy-using-proxy-pass)
- [Understanding Nginx Server and Location Blocks (DigitalOcean)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)

Comment: When you say the first URI segment, do you mean a URI like `/foo/bar` should be sent to `*.2:3000/foo` (with the `/bar/` completely removed)?

Comment: Hi @Richard. No, what I want to do is: when I go to a path like `/company` or `/company/workwithus`, NGINX should redirect me to `ip1:80/company` (or `ip1:80/company/workwithus`, whatever)... but when I go to a path like `/other_word` (wildcard word, not declared on NGINX config file) I need to get a redirect to `ip2:3000/other_word`... Do you understand me now? Thanks bro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `location / { ... }` block as your wildcard, as it matches any URI that will not match another `location` block.

You do not need a URI component in the `proxy_pass` statement, as you are not modifying the URI before sending it upstream. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

You can save on typing by specifying the `proxy_set_header` statements within the outer block and allowing them to be inherited by both `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.

For example:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

location ~ ^/(company|portfolio|services|contact|)(/|$) {
    proxy_pass         "http://private.ip.1:80";
}

location / {
    proxy_pass         "http://private.ip.2:3000";
}
```

Comment: That's right! Thank you for the simple configuration! Works like a charm. There is only one thing that's bad with this config, and is the basic website path. I mean, when I go to `http://example.com.ar/` I need to do `proxy_pass` to ip1:80 too. With this config, when I go to the web, I go directly to ip2:3000, without putting a word after the slash.

Comment: Can you send me the docs link for understand how you construct this part? `^/(company|portfolio|services|contact)(/|$)`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited the answer to add `/` to the regular expression. You can use [this website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) to help understand regular expressions.